# Regarding the Custom Page Button Link Action

Tags: custom-button

I have Created New Button Action or Link in Contact Object ,if i click the Custom button,i will Link to the Accountid of the Particular contact,after clicking the button i will redirect to Account Page
[image]

**But if Click the Button it is Not redirecting,it is Looping How to Rectify the Issue**

Comment: Try /{!Contact.AccountId__c }

Comment: @Devendra why we have to give /

Comment: @cloudcomputinginsalesforce It is a [HTML relative-URL](http://www.webreference.com/html/tutorial2/3.html) naming convention.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create one custom formula field on Contact which will capture AccountId. and then you can use this field in URL of a button.

[image]

Comment: why we have to use / infront of the formula

Comment: why we have to use Custom field , without  using this Field it is Not Possible ah?@Devendra